# C++ - Method that takes a pointer but receives an int

Tags: c++, pointers

I am wondering how would I deal with a call to a function when an integer is passed into a function that accepts a pointer? In my case hasPlayedInTeam() accepts a pointer to Team, however, received an int. This causes the Q_ASSERT to hang.

In addition, is my problem also known as a null pointer? My professor has used that term several times in lecture, but I am not sure what he was referring to.

```
//main.cpp
Person p1("Jack", 22, "UCLA");
Q_ASSERT(p1.hasPlayedInTeam(0) == false);


//person.cpp
bool Person::hasPlayedInTeam(Team *pTeam) {
  bool temp = false;
  foreach (Team* team, teamList) {
    if (team->getName() == pTeam->getName() {
      temp = true;
    }
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your call:

```
p1.hasPlayedInTeam(0)
```

the integer literal `0` is converted to a `NULL` pointer. So, you are not actually "receiving" an integer; you are passing an integer, the compiler can automatically cast it to the null pointer (given the definition for NULL).

I think you can fix the definition of `hasPlayedInTeam` by either asserting that its argument is not NULL, or by returning a default value when NULL is passed in:

```
//person.cpp
bool Person::hasPlayedInTeam(Team *pTeam) {
    assert(pTeam!=NULL); //-- in this case, your program will assert and halt
```

or:

```
//person.cpp
bool Person::hasPlayedInTeam(Team *pTeam) {
    if (pTeam == NULL)
         return false; //-- in this case, your program will not assert and continue with a sensible (it actually depends on how you define "sensible") return value
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it sounds like your problem is a null pointer.  A null pointer means that you have a pointer which isn't actually pointing to anything:

```
Team* team = NULL;
```

It so happens that in C++ `NULL` is a macro for the integer 0.  Stroustrup has [some comments](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null) on which one he prefers to use in code.

Answer (score 1):

Function hasPlayedInTeam() looks for the argument of type "Team" whereas you are passing the argument of type "integer" which is wrong....

Comment: The function is actually looking for a pointer to a Team object, so the integer 0 is a perfectly valid argument.

Comment: In this case 0 gets converted to a pointer (NULL) and so this is okay, however it wouldn't work with any other int

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that you are referring to a null pointer in that situation.

To treat the case when an int is passed, you can [overload](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/76-function-overloading/) the function and make it behave as you want it to do, when an int is passed.

Comment: However this would mean that if he passed NULL, the function call would be ambiguous and wouldn't compile (gave `error: call of overloaded ‘func(NULL)’ is ambiguous` on gcc4.6.1)

Comment: Good point, i haven't thought of that. How do you think this problem can be avoided? (starting from the premise that he did overload the function)

Comment: Interestingly, when I passed 0 to my overloaded func it called the int version, it was just NULL that caused troubles.  As to how to avoid it, I'm not sure you can in a general way, at best you could figure something out in a specific context, but the solution will probably just end up being giving the functions different names

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is `NULL` which is defined as `0` (in some standard header file, `cstddef` I think) so yes the integer you are passing is the null pointer.  `0` is the only (as far as I know) integer that will automatically (implicitly) be converted to a pointer of whatever type is needed.

In practice, I think most people prefer to use `NULL` instead of `0` for the null pointer.

I'm not sure why it is hanging however, dereferencing the `NULL` pointer (in your statement  `pTeam->getName()`) should cause the program to crash if you pass it `NULL`, not just hang.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the null pointer literal is one of the confused parts of the language. Let me try to recap:

1. For any type there is the concept of "pointer to that type". For example you can have integers and pointer to integers (`int x; int *y;`), doubles and pointer to doubles (`double x; double *y;`), Person and pointer to Person (`Person x,*y;`). If `X` is a type then "pointer to X" **is a type itself** and therefore you can even find pointers to pointers to integers (`int **x;`) or pointers to pointers to pointers to chars (`char ***x;`).
2. For any pointer type there is a `null pointer` **value**. It's a value that doesn't really point to an object, so it's an error to try to dereference it ("dereferencing" a pointer means reading or writing the object that is being pointed to). Note that the C++ language doesn't guarantee that you will get a message or a crash when you use a null pointer to get try to get to a non-existent pointed object but just that you should not do it in a program because consequences are unpredictable. The language simply assumes you are not going to do this kind of error.
3. How is the null pointer expressed in a program? Here comes the tricky part. For reasons that are beyond comprehension the C++ language uses a strange rule: if you get **any constant integer expression with value zero** then that can be (if needed) considered to be a null pointer for any type.

The last rule is extremely strange and illogical and for example means that

```
char *x = 0;     // x is a pointer to char with the null pointer value (ok)

char *y = (1-1); // exactly the same (what??)

char *z = !!    !!  !!    !!  !!       !!  
          !!!   !!  !!    !!  !!       !!
          !!!!  !!  !!    !!  !!       !!
          !! !! !!  !!    !!  !!       !!
          !!  !!!!  !!    !!  !!       !!
          !!   !!!  !!    !!  !!       !!
          !!    !!   !!!!!!   !!!!!!!  !!!!!!1; // Same again (!)
```

and this is true for any pointer type.

Why is the standard mandating that any expression and not just a zero literal can be considered the null pointer value? Really no idea.

Apparently Stroustrup also found the thing amusing instead of disgusting like it should be (the last example with the "NULL" text written with an odd number of negations is present on "The C++ Programming Language" book).

Also note that there is a `NULL` symbol defined in standard headers that provide a valid definition for a null pointer value for any type. In "C" a valid definition could have been `(void *)0` but this is not valid in C++ because void pointers cannot be converted implicitly to other pointer types like they do in "C".

Note also that you may find in literature the term `NUL` (only one L) but this is the ASCII character with code 0 (represented in C/C++ with `'\0'`) and is a **logically** distinct thing from a pointer or an integer number.

Unfortunately in C++ characters are integers too and therefore for example `'\0'` is a valid null pointer value and the same goes for `('A'-'A')` (they are integer constant expressions evaluating to zero).

C++11 increases complexity of these already questionable rules with `std::nullptr_t` and `nullptr`. I cannot explain those rules because I didn't understand them myself (and I'm not yet 100% sure I want to understand them).